# Display an image from PHP using header and echo

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, blob

For a school project I have to save images in a mysql database and then show those images on a website. To do so, I use the following code to save the images:

```
$link = $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', 'root', '');

$user = $_POST['user'];
$image = [];

$image = $_FILES['file'];
$image['string_scape'] = $link->quote(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

$link->query('INSERT INTO userImage VALUES(NULL, "'.$image['string_scape'].'", "'.$image['type'].'", '.$image['size'].', '.$user.', NOW())') or die (print_r($link->errorInfo()));

$link = null;
```

This is table I made for the images:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| File       | longblob | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Type       | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Size       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| User       | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Date_added | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And to show the images I use the following code:

```
//PHP file "show-image.php"
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=distribuidora', 'root', '');
$result = $link->query('SELECT * FROM userImage WHERE id = '.$_GET['id']) or die (print_r($link->errorInfo()));

$image = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header("Content-type:".$image["Type"]);
header("Content-Length:".$image["Size"]);
echo $image["File"];
```

The HTML:

```
<img src="show-image.php?id=1" alt="image" />
```

This is how I've done it for the last year and it used to work just fine, but since last week I can't make the image to be shown. I've tried different headers and the different solutions given in other questions in here, but still won't work.

Comment: try to enable the warning in Apache so we can know what warnings/errors it is generating

Comment: Your ID field is auto increment.  You do not need to pass NULL

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain the warnings are enabled, yet no errors are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error in `$image = $_FILES['file'];` u should name the file like this `$image = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and change the html to `<img src="show-image.php?id=1" alt="image" name='name' />`

Comment: No, that's why I'm passing the parameters with $_GET.